# How to remove KDE plasma completely from ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome

I installed KDE plasma and I removed it but I am not getting my desktop environment now. I installed gnome again but it does not default.please help me how can I remove KDE completely and set gnome as default DE?

Comment: try `apt autoremove && apt install ubuntu-desktop` and see for more help on setting a default desktop env here https://superuser.com/questions/685970/how-to-set-a-default-desktop-environment-at-system-start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the plasma-desktop dependencies like this `sudo apt depends plasma-desktop | grep Depends | cut -f2 -d: >> plasma-desktop-dependencies.txt` and can manually remove them by creating list of those and applying `sudo apt remove listed_packages` and then just install the ubuntu-desktop as it is a ready made gnome desktop environment.
Or try `apt remove plasma-desktop && apt autoremove && apt install ubuntu-desktop`

which will remove kde components and install the Ubuntu-gnome desktop with lightdm and to make sure to use lightdm as dm, run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and it supposed to pop up a window to choose between DMs, choose lightdm and edit `$HOME/.dmrc` and set

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome
```

to have gnome as default DE.

Comment: @AnishAnsari Can you retry as I have updated the answer?